# Bash check multiple word to match one word

Tags: bash, devops

i have a variable
`BACKUP_STATUS` which consists of many `SUCCESS` words

```
[ryt: i9]: echo $BACKUP_STATUS
SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS
```

Question:
I want to make a check so that if one of these words in a variable changes to something else, then it gives an error
I try like this

```
[[$BACKUP_STATUS = "SUCCESS"]] && echo true || echo false
```

but throws false

Comment: So true for SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS and false for SUCCESS SUCCESS NO_SUCCESS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[[ $(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$BACKUP_STATUS" | sort -u) == SUCCESS ]] && echo true || echo false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex with test command to search if "NO_SUCCESS" string is found

```
$ SUC="SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS"
$ NSUC="SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS NO_SUCCESS"
$ [[ $SUC =~ .*NO_SUCCESS.* ]] && echo "something wrong" || echo "everything is ok"
everything is ok
$ [[ $NSUC =~ .*NO_SUCCESS.* ]] && echo "something wrong" || echo "everything is ok"
something wrong
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if [[ " $BACKUP_STATUS" == *[^\ ]SUCCESS* || "$BACKUP_STATUS " == *SUCCESS[^\ ]* ]]
then
  echo unexpected status found
else
  echo only successes
fi
```

The idea is to search for a word which has something in front or in the back of SUCCESS. It's a bit clumsy, but I could not find a way to combine the two conditions into one.

Another possibility would be to use a loop:

```
error=0
for statusword in $BACKUP_STATUS
do
  if [[ $statusword != SUCCESS ]]
  then
    echo Unexpected status: $statusword
    error=1
    break
  fi
done
if (( error == 0 ))
then
  # all SUCCESS
  ...
fi
```

Both solutions work without creating a child process.

Answer (score 1):

I like extended globbing and parameter parsing for this.

```
$:  echo "[$BACKUP_STATUS]" # value with a fail
[ SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS NO_SUCCESS ]
$: shopt -s extglob         # set extended globbing

$: echo "[${BACKUP_STATUS//*( )SUCCESS*( )/}]"
[NO_]
$: [[ -z "${BACKUP_STATUS//*( )SUCCESS*( )/}" ]] && echo ok || echo no
no

$: BACKUP_STATUS=" SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS " # no fails
$: echo "[${BACKUP_STATUS//*( )SUCCESS*( )/}]"
[]
$: [[ -z "${BACKUP_STATUS//*( )SUCCESS*( )/}" ]] && echo ok || echo no
ok
```

Extended globbing lets you have zero-or-more spaces.
`${BACKUP_STATUS//*( )SUCCESS*( )/}` says return the value of $BACKUP_STATUS with every occurrence of `SUCCESS` with or without spaces before or behind removed.

If anything is left it was not a `SUCCESS` return, so `[[ -z ... ]]` checks for a zero-length return as all successes.

This doesn't require spawning any external procs. It's just Bash.